# Retuning a string in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I wanted to return following string, but I still couldn't get it done right for couple of hours. CAn anyone tell me what did I do wrong? Thank you.

```
<?php
return '<a href="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/mailhide/d?k=01_e8P8ju5xfBlbOiP--WjQ==&amp;c=dfdzsds-j7y0aJ6_d6Av9xqjfaDIluL9S_AOEw=" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com/recaptcha/mailhide/d?k\073301_e8P82df345sBlbOiP--WjQ\75\75\46c\75UJhOCfdfdfasdvuH1t-j7y0aJ6_d6AvqjfaDIluL9S_AOEw\075', '', 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=500,height=300'); return false;" title="Reveal this e-mail address">rs...</a>@gmail.com.com';
?>
```

Comment: Your quotes are incorrect.

Comment: use 'echo' instead of 'return'. This is a stupid question because these are the basics. And your string formatting (quotes) is not right, use an editor with syntax highlighting to see what's wrong.

Comment: Escape the latter `'`'s. The first ' is where the string starts, the next is where it stops. Make sure to escape any of them inbetween with a \ ... The return is for use inside functions to return data to where it was called. In your code there is no method, use a output method instead like echo or print. Good luck with your coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have single quotes in the JavaScript code in your `onclick` attribute.  You need to escape these by placing a backslash before each single quote.